# What are the verb conjugation names called in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, grammar-identification, new-latin, conjugation

What are the terms in Latin for the Latin verb conjugations? I would like to also know the Latin for the mixed conjugation (or if preferred that known as the io sub conjugation) and any term for verbs not in these conjugations, those irregular verbs.

Comment: I asked this question with an understanding that contemporary classical Greek writers recognised 3 conjugations, and the meaning of declinatio may have changed over time.

Comment: I forgot to include that the reason for this question is because I wish to be able to replace all the Non Latin headings in a Latin reference grammar with Latin headings.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a partial answer in Lingua Latina where there are the recognised modern conjugations and these are described as four declensions of verbs called conjugations.

Declinationes verborum sunt quattuor, 'coniugationes' quae vocantur:

Coniugatio prima      1. ~are
Coniugatio secunda    2. -ere
Coniugalio tertia     3. -ere
Coniugatio quarta     4. -ire

Ut 'sum sumus* declinantur verba quorum Infinitivus desi­nit in -esse, ut ab-esse...

And from scans of 17th Century Latin books by Martin-Luther-Universitat Halle-Wittenberg comes the following.

After seeing the above terms in Hans Oerberg's Lingua Latina per se Illustrata, I've now been able to find multiple usages elsewhere in searches such as in online forums and also in other books for the first four conjugation terms.

This includes the ablatives De Prima Coniugatione, De Secunda Coniugatione, De Tertia Coniugatione, De Quarta Coniugatione. For example these are found in the Latin Grammar Compendium Grammaticae Latinae MDCLXXXVI (https://digitale.bibliothek.uni-halle.de/vd17/content/pageview/11399863 )

Titles for specific irregular verbs are given in the Compendium Grammaticae Latinae of 1651 Compendium Grammaticae MDCLI   Compendium Grammaticae Latinae : ab Ipsis Grammaticae Authoribus adornatum, & singulari studio in usum Scholasticae Iuventutis, ita digestum, Ut Nec Libris Alphabeticis, nec Donati paradigmatibus amplius opus sit pueris, qui eo utuntur   ( https://digitale.bibliothek.uni-halle.de/vd17/content/structure/8784313 ) What can be described as the heading of the third book of this compliation by Casparum Rotelium of Frankffurt is ParadigmaTa Declinationum Et Conjugationum: Tam Regularium quàm Irregularium . For the four conjugations of verbs, in this book, they are called Primae Conjugationis, II. Conjugationis, III. Conjugationis, IV. Conjugationis and as part of, but after other individual verbs, Inquio, III Conjugationis.

The titles for the individual verbs are usually of the form of the form Conjugatio verbi fero, Conjugatio verbi sum, Conjugatio verbi possum, etc

Based on these it is not much of a stretch for a title "Irregular verb conjugations"  like Coniugatio verborum irregularium, or alternatively  De coniugatione verborum irregularium .

Comment: Quick text searches within De Lingua Latina by Marcus Terentius Varro and Attic Nights by Aulus Gellius wasn't effective. Slowly making way through these texts commencing with Attic Nights. Book II XXV of Attic nights showed use of term inaequalitas declinationum in specific contrast to proportionem based on Greek terminology, but going to see if there is consistent and repeated usage of any terms.